# Parsing strings that were saved to a text file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsstring, text-files

I save pieces of data from my Cocoa application into a text file. The text file contains information as shown:

```
foo1 -> foo2
blah -> lwjef
hi -> bye
hello -> goodbye
```

Now the first part of each row is given by the user, but I need to get the part of each row after the `->`. For example, if the user enters `foo1`, I want to output `foo2` after parsing the text file. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you post the code that you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse once:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSArray *lines = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
for (NSString *line in lines) {
    NSArray *values = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@" -> "];
    if ([values count] != 2) {
        continue;
    }
    [dictionary setObject:[values objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[values objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

Then query for keys:

```
NSString *input = @"foo1";
NSString *answer = [dictionary objectForKey:input]; //@"foo2"
```

---

However, if the data originally came from your own application in the first place you should probably do this, instead of a custom (and insecure) string format:

```
//For saving:
[dictionary writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
//For loading:
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Comment: @Kevin: If possible use NSDictionary's native saving/loading, instead of writing your own format. What for example happens if any of your strings contained the substring `"->"`? NSDictionary will handle this properly. You own code (and the one I posted above, on top) not so much.

Comment: Hmm good idea, but this txt file is generated from the app itself and it most 100% will not have any substrings "->". Anyway thanks for the post! I'll implement this once I get home.

Comment: Even if you're sure the file is never ever going to break your format it's still better to use existing and well-tested standards. Not only will you benefit from it's safety, but you will also benefit from not having to maintain your own and lengthy code and being able to instead reduce it to a single method call. Well, whatever, did it work for you?

Comment: Yup it did. Thanks, I forgot to say it was my answer :)

Comment: I'm sorry but this is probably the most useful code snippet I've ever used in my whole life. Its been helpful for me in so many occasions! Thanks so much once again.